# is there a way i would remove a package from my Vue3 cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I recently just installed vee-validate into my Vue3 cli and then tried it but it didn't work for me and now i need to remove it. So can you help show me how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You simply remove it from the dependencies in your package.json file and then remove any place you imported it into your main.js or components.